How to access a hierarch dart class attribute?
How can I manage image paths for different categories, like logos and backgrounds, in Dart? I tried using nested classes like in Java, but Dart doesn't support that! What are the best practices or alternatives to handle this?

void main() {
  print(Images.background.lake); // it dosn't work!
}

class Images {
  class Portrait {
    final traditional = 'assets/images/portrait/traditional.png';
    final environmental = 'assets/images/portrait/environmental.png';
  }

  class Background {
    final nature = 'assets/images/background/nature.png';
    final lake = 'assets/images/background/lake.png';
  }
}




The Images class contains nested classes _Portrait and _Background, organizing image paths for easy access and allowing for additional nested classes as needed.
class Images {
  // Nested classes for image-specific path

  // portrait images
  static const portrait = _Portrait();

  // background images
  static const background = _Background();
}

class _Portrait {
  const _Portrait();

  // portrait directory path
  static const String _portraitDirPath = 'assets/images/portrait/';

  final String traditional = '${_portraitDirPath}traditional.png';
  final String environmental = '${_portraitDirPath}environmental.png';
}

class _Background {
  const _Background();

  // background directory path
  static const String _backgroundDirPath = 'assets/images/background/';

  final String nature = '${_backgroundDirPath}nature.png';
  final String lake = '${_backgroundDirPath}lake.png';
}

Then, you can access each image path through their chained member access (dotted notation), like:
void main() {
  print(Images.portrait.traditional);
  print(Images.background.nature);
} 

